# How to link two existing records through many to many relationship

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy

I need to add `roles` to `staff`, the following code works but somehow it does not allow to add the same role to multiple staff. if the same role gets assigned again, the previous assignment is deleted from the secondary table! why is this happening

```
staff_roles = Table('staff_roles', Base.metadata,
    Column('staff_id', Integer, ForeignKey('staff.id')),
    Column('role_id', Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id'))
)

class Staff(Base):
    __tablename__="staff"
    id=             Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    img=            Column(String)
    civil_id=       Column(Integer)
    nationality=    Column(String)
    disabled=       Column(Boolean, default=False)
    created_at=     Column(DateTime)
    updated_at=     Column(DateTime)

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    roles = relationship("Roles", uselist=True, secondary=staff_roles, back_populates="staff", lazy='raise')



class Roles(Base):
    __tablename__="roles"
    id=             Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name=           Column(String)
    staff = relationship("Staff", uselist=False, secondary=staff_roles, back_populates="roles", lazy='raise')



def add_role_to_staff(db: Session, user_id:int, role_ids:list):
    roles = db.query(tables.Roles).options(joinedload(tables.Roles.staff)).filter(tables.Roles.id.in_(role_ids)).all()
    staff = db.query(tables.Staff).options(joinedload(tables.Staff.roles)).filter(tables.Staff.user_id == user_id).first()
    if len(roles) == 0 or staff is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="role or staff does not exist")

    for role in roles:
        staff.roles.append(role)
        
    try:
        db.commit()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        db.rollback()
        process_db_error(e)
```

from the logs:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:DELETE FROM staff_roles WHERE staff_roles.staff_id = %(staff_id)s AND staff_roles.role_id = %(role_id)s
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'staff_id': 2, 'role_id': 2}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:INSERT INTO staff_roles (staff_id, role_id) VALUES (%(staff_id)s, %(role_id)s)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'staff_id': 1, 'role_id': 2}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMIT
```

Why does it delete?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is interesting, the issue was in the `Roles` table in `staff` relationship. `uselist` should be `True`.